# Convert to Full Class Name on Checkout, Commit Using Var

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lint

I work for a company who's preferred coding style requires the use of `var`. Personally, I really dislike this and find that it makes it harder for me to understand exactly what's going on.

Is there any way for me to automatically checkout code and convert it to using the explicit type names but then do the inverse when I commit something and automatically convert it back to `var`?

Comment: If it's "use `var` everywhere you possibly can", it's probably a bad policy. If it's "use `var` when the type if either obvious or less relevant" then I'd strongly encourage you to embrace it. Doe the type turn out to be *important to understanding how the code works* in the cases where you're not understanding the code?

Comment: No. We don't have.  But I didn't understand why you are confusing. You can able to see the type of variable , just by mouse hovering

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it seems to be "use `var` everywhere". I agree it's a bad policy IMHO, but I've been at this company a few weeks so I'm not going to rock the boat too much just yet.

I don't have any specific instances where I can't understand what's going on because of `var` being used (I'd just hover over it), I more meant in general I find that it increases my cognitive load, even in instances where the type is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the refactoring to do it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-var-to-explicit-type?view=vs-2019 and also the article as a discussion entry point to argue against using `var` everywhere.

> Following are some reasons to declare a variable with an explicit type:
>
> • To improve the code's readability.
>
> • When you don't want to initialize the variable in the declaration.
>
> However, var must be used when a variable is initialized with an anonymous type and the properties of the object are accessed at a later point. For more information, see Implicitly typed local variables (C#).

However there is no automatic easy way for the back and forth you require.

Comment: That's a shame, I was aware I could do it like this, was just hoping it could be automated in a similar fashion to how unix/windows line-ending conversions are.

Might be time to write my own tool.